# Is this question really too broad

Tags: discussion

[This question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/190890/how-to-avoid-community-licences-cost-for-public-user-in-salesforce/190891#190891) has been put on hold as too broad but I feel that it is actually reasonably clear and answerable in a simple way with the licence types of Customer Community and Customer Community Login being compared?

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, the question is closed as "Primarily Opinion-Based" instead of "Too Broad". (Just pointing that out. I don't have any voice on this matter though)

Answer (score 2):

Agreed.

Question or expectation is clear and there is a clear known answer that can be given. Salesforce licenses and contractual possibilities are not "opinion-based".

I have re-opened the question.